# Java Passing a file to a method error?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, filenotfoundexception

Hello I'm currently working on an assignment for my programming course and I need to pass a file to another method, however, I keep getting the error message:

**"Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: USPopulation.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)"**

And I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I tried being more specific with the path of the file and that didn't work.

Here is my work, if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great :) (also ignore the ArrayList version, I haven't gotten there yet.) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class populationsArrays 
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
   {
       // Array Version
       ArrayVersion();
       System.out.println("Finished Array Version of Assignment");

       // ArrayList Version
       ArrayListVersion();
       System.out.println("Finshed ArrayList Version of Assignment");
   }

   // Method for ArrayVersion
   public static void ArrayVersion() throws IOException
   {


       // Array to use for Population data
       int[] population =  new int[39];

       // Call the method to get data into array
       population = getDataFromFile("USPopulation.txt");


       if(population == null)
       {
           System.out.println("Error: Population did not load");
           return;
       }


   }

   // Method to get data from specified "filename" into an array of ints
   public static int[] getDataFromFile(String USPopulation) throws IOException
   {
       final int SIZE = 39;
       // Array to use for Population data
       int[] population =  new int[SIZE];
       int i = 0;
       // Opening file
       File file = new File("USPopulation.txt");
       Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

       while(inputFile.hasNext() && i < population.length)
       {
           population[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
           i++;
       }


       inputFile.close();

       return population;
   }

   // Method for ArrayListVersion
   public static void ArrayListVersion() throws IOException
   {

   }
}
```

error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: USPopulation.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
at populationsArrays.getDataFromFile(populationsArrays.java:48)
at populationsArrays.ArrayVersion(populationsArrays.java:27)
at populationsArrays.main(populationsArrays.java:10)
```

EDIT: I tried changing the file name to the path of the file for both the getDataFromFile and the new File,but none of those worked

EDIT: I am using Windows 10, and I have to use File

Last Edit: I finally got it to work, I started a new project file in a different location on my desktop and saved the USPopulation file in the same folder with the new project file and pasted my work and did what Hunt wrote. Thank you so much!

Comment: Right after you construct the file `new File(...)` do `System.out.println(file.getPath())`, use that to verify where the file actually is vs where your program thinks it should be and adjust as such.

Comment: I'd say that the problem is likely to be exactly what the error message says it is.  If there is in fact a file by the given name somewhere on the system at all, then probably your program's working directory is different from the one where the file resides.

Comment: Does your assignment require you to use `File`? If yes, your assignment is at best 5 years late. Use nio instead.

Comment: hi, which os are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of writing just the file name try giving the complete file path with the file name.
for eg.

```
//code
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\HUNT\\DocumentsUSPopulation.txt");
```

this will surely work.

And also give the same path for the method getdatafromfile("");

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a file to the path it assumes it is in your Current Working Directory (CWD).  Your CWD would be where you started your program from. You can call System.out.println(file.getPath()) to verify that the file was searched for in your CWD, as suggested by ug_.

If it's not in your CWD you can give an absolute location of the file path like this (if on Windows):

```
getDataFromFile("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\USPopulation.txt");
```

You must escape the \ by putting another \ in front of it.

Comment: Or use `/` instead of \\.